# Titan: NullPointerException is thrown instead of IllegalArgumentException

Tags: titan

In this code

```
Vertex page            = graph.getVertex(pageId);
```

If `pageId` doesn't exist it should throw `IllegalArgumentException` but instead it throws `NullPointerException`. Here `page` is `null`.

I am catching `IllegalArgumentException` exception but its never catched. Why?

Comment: Maybe `graph` is `null`, or `getVertex` doesn't do a `null` check.

Comment: no graph is not null. and there is no need to check `null` if a vertex doent exist Titan throws `IllegalArgumentException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `pageId` is null then standard Blueprints behavior is to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` which is enforced by this test:

https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/blob/2.5.0/blueprints-test/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/VertexTestSuite.java#L82

That said, I think you are talking about vertex existence (as you wrote "if `pageId` doesn't exist).  In the case of existence, standard Blueprints behavior is to return `null` if the identifier does not find a vertex with it.  This behavior is enforced by this test:

https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/blob/2.5.0/blueprints-test/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/VertexTestSuite.java#L157

As you can see in my REPL session, Titan works as expected given the tests:

```
gremlin> g = TitanFactory.open('conf/titan-cassandra.properties')
==>titangraph[cassandrathrift:127.0.0.1]
gremlin> g.getVertex(4)
==>v[4]
gremlin> g.getVertex(8)
==>null
gremlin> g.getVertex(null)
Vertex id can not be null
Display stack trace? [yN] y
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Vertex id can not be null
```

This is all expected behavior given the Blueprints API.  As far as "why" it works this way....I think that `IllegalArgumentException` wouldn't be appropriate for a "not found" situation.  At the end of the day, this was largely just a design decision and we thought that returning `null` was better than tossing an exception to provide feedback on "existence".